# Horizontal and vertical center a fixed width/height element in svg

Tags: css, html, svg

I have the following html code:

```html
<div class="youtube-preview" 
     style="background-color: #333; position: relative; width: 420px; height:316px">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="80" height="55"
     style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" ry="0" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

This produces a div that has a smaller box inside centered both vertically and horizontally, which is the exact effect I want.

However, I want to convert this to SVG. 
I've spent the last 2 days looking for **a way to center an element (without scaling) in a fluid dimensioned SVG and couldn't find anything**.

Is this even possible? Seems something pretty basic...

**Notes:**

- The "black box" can have any width and height and the ratio can change.
- The inner box has fixed dimensions and should not scale (up or down)

Comment: Can use this trick: inner box is a `<div>` which overlays the `<svg>`. Else you have to dynamically update the inner box's (x,y) value with `translate`  with each time the dimensions of SVG is updated.

Answer (score 3):

No. This can't be done - without using some javascript to resize and reposition the inner box.

If you want your SVG to be responsive, you have to accept that everything inside it will scale also.

This may be possible eventually with SVG 2, but not with SVG 1.1 and current browsers.